# IPython Console in Spyder(Anaconda) is truncating output

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

The IPython console in Spyder(Anaconda) is truncating the upper part of the output when the output is large.
Eg I was trying to see what all is in the *os* module.
I wrote the command `help(os)` and the output was very big, so it truncated some of the top entries. What should I do to see the full output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is done to avoid blocking Spyder when too much output is going to be printed in the console.

You can increase the current limit by going to

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Display > Buffer`

However, if you want to read the help associated to an object, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in macOS) in front of it and the get its help rendered in another Spyder pane called *Help*.